# Calculate all possible combinations of traits, while taking into account trait rarity/limits

Tags: math

I'm working on a unique NFT generator and I need a mathematical equation to help me calculate how many combinations I can create from an *X amount* of layers of traits/properties.

For example, say I have 4 layers, with 5 traits in each layer.
The expression for this is simple, its 5 x 5 x 5 x 5 = 625 possible combinations.

Now, what if I want one of the traits in one of the layers to only be used in, for example, lets say, 10 combinations.

What would be the expression to calculate the possible combinations of something like that, while taking these limits for specific traits into account?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming-related and therefore off-topic. It is purely a math question. Math questions _might_ be on-topic at https://math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the case into combinations *with* that trait:

```
1 x 5 x 5 x 5 = 125
```

and combinations *without* that trait:

```
4 x 5 x 5 x 5 = 500
```

Limit the combinations *with* that trait to 10, and you get:

```
10 + 500 = 510
```

If you have multiple restricted traits, it makes sense to combine them, so as to get the greatest possible use of the unrestricted traits.